# Can you package and install in a Windows Service with a Windows store app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I know you can call Windows Services from a Windows store app as described [here](http://rarcher.azurewebsites.net/Post/PostContent/23), so I was wondering if it would be possible to install a custom one packaged with a Windows store app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean a WCF (web) service vs. a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (the latter isn't addressed [in the link you referenced](http://rarcher.azurewebsites.net/Post/PostContent/23)). Regardless, your application will not pass certification if it requires a loopback connection to a service hosted on the same machine.

You can [set this up for testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx), but note:

> **Enable loopback for network access**
>
> Network communications using an IP loopback address cannot be used for
> interprocess communication (between two different apps) since this is
> restricted by network isolation. Network communication using an IP
> loopback address is allowed within an app within the same process for
> communication purposes.
>
> A developer may want to use loopback for testing or debugging
> purposes, even though that capability will not be available for
> customers. For example, an app may want to download data from a web
> service. For development purposes, the developer wants to test the app
> on a single computer that is configured with the web service locally
> on 127.0.0.1.
>
> **Warning**  Loopback is only permitted for development purposes. Usage by
> apps installed outside of Visual Studio is not permitted.